# what is the difference between memory and network on the column 'input size/Record' on spark ui?

Tags: apache-spark

I have some problem while running spark streaming in my cluster.

First, I know that speculative tasks are caused by slow execution of some executors, but some task that are **not** speculative also running slow with the 'input size/Record' column showing network while the other show memory. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

so can someone tell me what is the difference between memory and network on the column 'input size/Record'? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The size of the data is not a problem here. Based on the screenshot all partitions are more or less of the same size.

What is really the issue is data locality. Majority of data can be accessed locally, however the problematic ones, are forced to use `RACK_LOCAL`, and since it takes much longer than expected speculative execution kicks in, and tries with `ANY`.

There is not enough information here to full diagnose the issue, but one thing you can try is increasing `spark.locality.wait` property (default is 3 seconds).

Comment: The problem I solved before was that I allocated 16 executors to spark, but because the default value of `spark.locality.wait.process` and `spark.locality.wait.node` was too large, most tasks were allocated to a small part of the executors, so I had to turn down the value of `spark.locality.wait.process` and `spark.locality.wait.node`